# What is the difference in the operation of JS functions with checkboxes in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I'm trying to figure out how to work with a checkbox using JS.

Why does `setAttribute("disabled", "")` work only when I click checkbox class`s "ch2"?

HTML:

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="ch1" name="ch1" onclick="fn_for_two_chb()">
<label for="ch1">ch1</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="ch2" name="ch2" onclick="fn_for_two_chb()">
<label for="ch2">ch2</label>
```

JS:

```js
const chb_1 = document.querySelector('.ch1')
const chb_2 = document.querySelector('.ch2')

function fn_for_two_chb() {
    if (chb_1.checked == true) {
            chb_2.setAttribute("disabled", "");
    } else {
            chb_1.removeAttribute("disabled", "");
            chb_2.removeAttribute("disabled", "");
    }

    if (chb_2.checked == true) {
            chb_1.setAttribute("disabled", "");
    } else{
            chb_1.removeAttribute("disabled", "");
            chb_2.removeAttribute("disabled", "");
    }
  }
```

But when I split this into two functions and assign them to different checkboxes in HTML, it works.

HTML:

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="ch1" name="ch1" onclick="fn_chb_1()">
<label for="ch1">ch1</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="ch2" name="ch2" onclick="fn_chb_2()">
<label for="ch2">ch2</label>
```

JS:

```js
function fn_chb_1() {

    if (chb_1.checked == true) {
            chb_2.setAttribute("disabled", "");
    } else {
            chb_1.removeAttribute("disabled", "");
            chb_2.removeAttribute("disabled", "");
    }
  }

function fn_chb_2() {

    if (chb_2.checked == true) {
            chb_1.setAttribute("disabled", "");
    } else {
            chb_1.removeAttribute("disabled", "");
            chb_2.removeAttribute("disabled", "");
    }
  }
```

Comment: In your first block of code, your second `else` overwrites the first `if`

Comment: Your code acts as if both checkboxes have been clicked, not one or the other.

Comment: @freedomn-m, you are right. I didn't take into account that the second condition will be met anyway and overwrites the first if.
Changed the first block to:
`function fn_for_two_chb(){
if (chb_1.checked == true){
chb_2.setAttribute("disabled", "");
} else if (chb_2.checked == true) {
chb_1.setAttribute("disabled", "");
} else{
chb_1.removeAttribute("disabled", "");
chb_2.removeAttribute("disabled", "");
 }
}`

Answer (score 0):

A bit more tricky.

```js
const chb_1 = document.querySelector('.ch1');
const lbl1 = chb_1.closest("label");
const chb_2 = document.querySelector('.ch2');
const lbl2 = chb_2.closest("label");

document.getElementById("checks").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (!tgt.matches("[type=checkbox]")) return; // not a checkbox
  const isChk1 = tgt.matches("[name=ch1]");
  const checked = tgt.checked;
  chb_1.removeAttribute("disabled");
  chb_2.removeAttribute("disabled");
  if (checked) {
    chb_1[isChk1 ? "removeAttribute":"setAttribute"   ]("disabled","disabled");
    chb_2[isChk1 ? "setAttribute"   :"removeAttribute"]("disabled","disabled");
  }
  lbl1.classList.toggle("disabled",chb_1.disabled);
  lbl2.classList.toggle("disabled",chb_2.disabled);
});
```

```css
.disabled { color:grey; }
```

```html
<div id="checks">
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="ch1" name="ch1" />ch1</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="ch2" name="ch2" />ch2</label>
</div>
```

you really should consider radios

```js
const chb_1 = document.querySelector('.ch1');
const lbl1 = chb_1.closest("label");
const chb_2 = document.querySelector('.ch2');
const lbl2 = chb_2.closest("label");

document.getElementById("checks").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (!tgt.matches("[name=rad]")) return; // not a checkbox
  const isChk1 = tgt.matches(".ch1");
  const checked = tgt.checked;
  lbl1.classList.toggle("disabled",chb_2.checked);
  lbl2.classList.toggle("disabled",chb_1.checked);
});
```

```css
.disabled { color:grey; }
```

```html
<div id="checks">
  <label><input type="radio" class="ch1" name="rad" />ch1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" class="ch2" name="rad" />ch2</label>
</div>
```